# You have an error in your SQL syntax; syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `users` ( `id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `hex_id` VARCHAR(10' at line 25

Tags: mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `users` ( `id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `hex_id` VARCHAR(10' at line 25

```
CREATE TABLE `characters` (
  `id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'John',
  `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Doe',
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `cash` INT(9) DEFAULT 500,
  `bank` INT(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT 5000,
  `phone_number` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dob` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `story` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `new` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,  
  `deleted` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deletion_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `gender` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `jail_time` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dirty_money` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `gang_type` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `jail_time_mobster` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `judge_type` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `iswjob` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hex_id` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `steam_id` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `community_id` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `license` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Uknown',
  `ip` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Uknown',
  `rank` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE `users_whitelist` (
  `id` INT(11) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `steam_id` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `power` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `admin_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `user_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `user_ip` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: The primary key of a table cannot accept nulls. Change the `NULL` to `NOT NULL` in the `id` column of all tables.

Comment: I predict that you execute these CREATE queries from your program as single multi-query batch, but you use the execution method which does not support multiquery. This problem is detected firstly, and you receive your current error message. But after you fix this then you'll meet the error described above.

Answer (score 2):

`id` should be `not null`

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table banks(bank_id number int(30) primary key,
                   bank_name char(40) not null,
                   location varchar(21) default ,
                   bank_phone number(20) unique,
                  employee_id number(19) not null);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

```
Create Table class
(
Class_no in not null auto_increment,
Class_name varchar(50) not null,
Lev_no varchar(50)not null,
Index_index_add (cl_name,lev_no)
)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The initial question doesn't contain any table named `class`

Comment: Hello, please add some description about what the code does.
[How to give a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)